# i have connected two tables(Login and addresstable) and now i want to view data from Addresstable in My View in cake php

Tags: cakephp

this is my controller function and I want to pass all data in my address_view
but the only Id is Passed When I die $xyz in my address_view.ctp

```
      public function view_address($id = null)
            {
                $this->loadModel('Addresstable');

                $data = $this->Addresstable->findAllByUserId($id);
                $this->set('xyz',$id);
                // pr($xyz);die;
                $xyz=$this->data;
            }
```

and this Is My view_address.ctp

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>


<table>


    <tr> 
        <td><?php  pr($xyz);die; echo $xyz['Addresstable']['user_id']; ?></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>   
       <td>House No :<?php echo $xyz['Addresstable']['houseno']; ?></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>Block :<?php echo $xyz['Addresstable']['block']; ?></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>Street :<?php echo $xyz['Addresstable']['street']; ?></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td> City :<?php echo $xyz['Addresstable']['city']; ?></td>   
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><td> State :<?php echo $xyz['Addresstable']['state']; ?></td></td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

> **Error Message:** Missing Controller Error: AddresstablesController could not be found. Error: Create the class AddresstablesController
>   below in file: app\Controller\AddresstablesController.php

Comment: Missing Controller

Error: AddresstablesController could not be found.

Error: Create the class AddresstablesController below in file: app\Controller\AddresstablesController.php

<?php
class AddresstablesController extends AppController {

}
Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create app\View\Errors\missing_controller.ctp

Comment: What is your controller name? What is the URL you are requesting?

Comment: controller Name is LoginsController

Comment: First change `$this->set('xyz',$id);$xyz=$this->data;` with `$xyz=$data;$this->set('xyz',$id);`

Comment: My bad change to `$xyz=$data;$this->set('xyz',$xyz);`

Answer (score 1):

you set data array wrong way,

Try this

```
public function view_address($id = null)
                    {
                        $this->loadModel('Addresstable');

                        $data = $this->Addresstable->findAllByUserId($id);
                        $xyz=$data;
                        $this->set(compact('xyz','id'));                  

                    }
```